# Advantages of treating function as an object

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Recently I came across a simple Command pattern implementation in JavaScript that uses function as an object instead of pure object to define functionality:

```
var CommandManager = (function() {
  function CommandManager() {}

  CommandManager.executed = [];
  CommandManager.unexecuted = [];

  CommandManager.execute = function execute(cmd) {
    cmd.execute();
    CommandManager.executed.push(cmd);
  };

  CommandManager.undo = function undo() {
    var cmd1 = CommandManager.executed.pop();
    if (cmd1 !== undefined){
      if (cmd1.unexecute !== undefined){
        cmd1.unexecute();
      }
      CommandManager.unexecuted.push(cmd1);
    }
  };

  CommandManager.redo = function redo() {
    var cmd2 = CommandManager.unexecuted.pop();

    if (cmd2 === undefined){
      cmd2 = CommandManager.executed.pop();
      CommandManager.executed.push(cmd2); 
      CommandManager.executed.push(cmd2); 
    }

    if (cmd2 !== undefined){
      cmd2.execute();
      CommandManager.executed.push(cmd2); 
    }
  };

  return CommandManager;
})();
```

and the usage:

```
CommandManager.execute({
  execute: function(){
    // do something
  },
  unexecute: function(){
    // undo something
  }
});

//call unexecute of prev. command
CommandManager.undo(); 
//call execute of prev. command
CommandManager.redo();
```

My question would be, is there any advantages in defining CommandManager function this way, instead of directly defining properties on object literal and assigning it back to `var CommandManager`

Comment: The global scope is not polluted by defining properties of an object which isn't the global object. The self-calling anonymous function style is widely overused for no good reason.

Comment: This pattern is to close any access from the outside in function. nothing can modify what's inside the self closed function

Comment: @Anonymous0day: The only local variables that are not exposed are inside functions. There is nothing in the scope that is not exposed to the outside.

Comment: @Guffa you're so right ! my brain just correct it to have a benefict of the design pattern, it was an error :-)

Answer (score 1):

The only use for that would be that you have a function that does absolutely nothing:

```
CommandManager(); // does nothing, returns undefined
```

Other than that, you can just as well write the code as an object literal and use `this` to avoid it being dependant on its own name:

```
var CommandManager = {
  executed: [],
  unexecuted: [],

  execute: function execute(cmd) {
    cmd.execute();
    this.executed.push(cmd);
  },

  undo: function undo() {
    var cmd1 = this.executed.pop();
    if (cmd1 !== undefined){
      if (cmd1.unexecute !== undefined){
        cmd1.unexecute();
      }
      this.unexecuted.push(cmd1);
    }
  },

  redo: function redo() {
    var cmd2 = this.unexecuted.pop();

    if (cmd2 === undefined){
      cmd2 = this.executed.pop();
      this.executed.push(cmd2); 
      this.executed.push(cmd2); 
    }

    if (cmd2 !== undefined){
      cmd2.execute();
      this.executed.push(cmd2); 
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: This is not really the same thing ! in your version anyone can access `executed` or `unexecuted` but not in the OP version ! and other subtilities . . .

Comment: @Anonymous0day also in OP version you can access `CommandManager.executed` , for it to be private it shouldn't be returned as property of CommandManager-obj ( `var executed = [];` inside closure )

Comment: @maioman -:( i haven't read correctly OP code ! you're right in reality Guffa is totaly right too.

Comment: OP code use this design pattern but without the advantages it can provide, so there is no need to use it in this case !

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.